# Detect a DIV open and close and apply styles to match what already exist

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

There's no real easy way for me to explain what I'm trying to do other than simply post some code and ask how I'd write a jQuery or PHP script to do what I need to do to make it work regardless of the comments added to the forum post.  Make two files:  index.php and style.css and paste the following information into them.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Carswipe - TEST</title>      
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="parent">
            <p>TEST</p>
            <div class="child_1">
                <p>STUFF</p>
                <div class="child_2">
                    <p>MORE STUFF</p>
                    <div class="child_1">
                        <p>EVEN MORE</p>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="child_1">
                        <p>JUNK</p>
                        <div class="child_2">
                            <p>ANDS TUFF</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="child_2">
                            <p>TEST</p>
                            <div class="child_1">
                                <p>TEST</p>
                                <div class="child_2">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit felis accumsan turpis pretium tempor. Duis eu turpis nunc, ut euismod nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin eu eros mollis dui fringilla sodales. Curabitur venenatis tincidunt felis ac congue. Maecenas at odio dui, sit amet congue sapien. Proin placerat feugiat eros, non mollis quam pharetra at. Duis gravida eleifend ligula nec auctor. Fusce nulla diam, fringilla non ultrices in, iaculis eu tellus. Sed mollis consequat turpis sit amet facilisis. Donec pretium luctus aliquet. Curabitur placerat varius purus vel congue. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur vitae eros sed turpis sollicitudin mattis. Morbi venenatis pulvinar nunc, at vulputate massa placerat a. Nam et tortor id nisi consequat tempor eget sit amet risus. Praesent bibendum, velit eu hendrerit porttitor, elit mauris posuere nisl, non pellentesque est leo a quam.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="child_2">
                                    <p>TEST</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="child_2">
                    <p>MORE TEST</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="child_1">
                <p>TESTING MULTIPLE LINES</p>
                <p>TADA</p>
                <div class="child_2">
                    <p>TEST</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
            <p>JUNK</p>
            <div class="child_1">
                <p>AND STUFF</p>
                <div class="child_2">
                    <p>AND THINGS</p>
                </div>
                <div class="child_2">
                    <p>HEYO</p>
                    <p>PLEASE!</p>
                    <div class="child_1">
                        <p>TEST1</p>
                        <div class="child_2">
                            <p>TEST2</p>
                            <div class="child_1">
                                <p>TEST3</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="child_1">
                                <p>TEST4</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="child_1">
                                <p>TEST5</p>
                                <div class="child_2">
                                    <p>TEST6</p>
                                    <div class="child_1">
                                        <p>TEST</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="child_1">
                                        <p>TEST</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="child_2">
                            <p>TEST7</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="child_1">
                        <p>TEST8</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
/* Links */
a{color:#7F0404;text-decoration:none}
a:hover{color:#5E5E5E;text-decoration:underline}

/* Core Style */
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%}
body{font:90% Tahoma;background:#5E5E5E url('images/fell-hall.png') no-repeat top center}
#container{width:1004px;margin:0 auto -91px auto}

p{padding:2px 10px 2px 20px}
.parent{margin:8px 8px 8px 0px;border:1px solid #bbbcbf;border-radius:8px;background-color:#fff}
.child_1:nth-child(even){border:1px solid #bbbcbf;border-radius:8px;margin:8px 8px 8px 30px;background-color:#f7f7f8}
.child_1:nth-child(odd){border:1px solid #bbbcbf;border-radius:8px;margin:8px 8px 8px 30px;background-color:#f7f7f8}
.child_2:nth-child(even){border:1px solid #bbbcbf;border-radius:8px;margin:8px 8px 8px 30px;background-color:#fff}
.child_2:nth-child(odd){border:1px solid #bbbcbf;border-radius:8px;margin:8px 8px 8px 30px;background-color:#fff}
```

Now, view the index.php file.  This is what I want the forum posts to look like.  You might recognize it as what the Reddit Stylize Extension look like (for at least Chrome) when viewing Reddit posts and the subsequent comments within them.

The problem is, that the div's are created by the users and thus, cannot have hand-coded classes for each.  It must determine how many div's are open, how many are closed, and apply the proper parent/child class appropriately.  I have been unable to wrap my head around how to do this and I'm pretty sure it would be a really simple jQuery or PHP script.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: asking for the community to write a script for you is not a particularly appropriate use of the site.

Comment: It's not necessarily asking for the script to be made but rather, if someone knows of a jQuery function to determine the number of times a tag is opened (in this case, for nested divs) or is closed and apply styles with that, it would help.  I've attempted to Google search for anything that is similar to what I need to do and have not found any jQuery or PHP function that does anything similar to what I need.

Comment: perhaps, but determining how deeply nested a tag is in jQuery is a very trivial problem. read the jQuery documentation on selectors and your way will be clear.

Comment: In the markup, what indicates whether a div is open or closed?  How would a script know?  I just see a lot of nested divs.

Comment: Essentially there is always a parent to start the original comment.  Any reply to that comment is a greyish color.  Any reply to that reply is white again.  It nests like that.  However, if, say there are 3 replies for the same parent comment, all three would be grey and only have a nested white div (and so on alternating) **IF** there were replies to one of those three comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you should care about what is open and what closed. You should only care for the nesting level as that is what determines the styling..

I believe this is what you want

```
$('#container div')
    .each(function(){
        var length = $(this).parentsUntil('#container').length;
        if (length){
            var alternate = 2 - (length % 2 );
            $(this).addClass('child_' + alternate);
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('parent');
        }
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/wNvwv/2/

---

Also you do not need the `nth-child` selectors in the CSS. Just the two differenct classes `.child_1` and `.child_2` which determine the alternating style **per depth**.

(*the `odd` and `even` are the same in your code anyway..*)

Comment: That worked terrifically.  Thank you very much!!  I really appreciate you taking the time.  It is my goal to begin learning jQuery more as it seems extremely powerful.